# How to prevent the focus ring from a Shadcn-UI/Tailwind CSS button element?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, shadcnui

I am using a custom **Tailwind** button from **Shadcn-UI** in my React component:

```
<Button
    variant="default"
    className="focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0 focus-visible:ring-0"
>
    BUTTON
</Button>
```

As you can see in the code, I am struggling to prevent the ugly ring that appears around the button when it comes in focus, i.e. upon click. But nothing seems to be working. Neither `ring-0` works, nor even `outline-none`. Is there any Tailwind class that I am missing out on? Even inline style as below (with `!important`, no less!), which I don’t want to depend on anyway, failed to do the job:

```
style={{ outline: "none !important" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Button
    variant="default"
    className="focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-offset-0"
>
    BUTTON
  </Button>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation or references to the documentation that explain how your code works.

Comment: @GeorgeButter 
I just looked at the component `Button` in `@/components/ui/button.tsx` and Reset the Tailwind classes